# WordPress, wp-content files

Tags: wordpress

I will ask something that I don't realy know if is correct.

in my WordPress installation, I have into wp-content two php files (except the index.php). That two files are they autoloaded from WordPress in some how? Or are they stay there safe ?

Ok. That files are wp-cache-config.php and w3-total-cache-config-ifeed.gr.php

Comment: It would be really helpful if you named those files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you don't need to worry about those files. They are needed for the Cache plugin you have installed and you don't need to tamper with them. They are perfectly safe.